# DELETE запрос к серверу через $http возвращает статус 404

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http, rest

Я пишу To-Do List приложение на AngularJs, у приложения должна быть возможность удалять задачи, Для этого мне надо с приложения отправить соответсвующий запрос к серверу, но получаю статус 404, в то время как через расширение postman статус запроса приходит 200. GET запрос с приложения к серверу для получения колекции всех задач проходит без проблем.

**Код запроса:**

```
deleteTask: function (task) {
  $log.log(task._id);
  $http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: 'http://localhost:3005/api/tasks/' + task._id,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $log.log(response);
  });
}
```

**Скриншот запроса с приложения:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Скриншот запроса с расширения Postman:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А без 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  пробовали?

Comment: да, content-type дописал потому что у меня до этого была проблема с запросом POST, у него Form-Data была обьектом, прийшлось добавить content-type и form-data переобразовать в urlencoded, думал возможно и здесь что то повлияет, ну это явно проблема не с сервером, через консольные утилиты и другие ПО запросы работают на ура. Это приложение просто розвернутый yeoman с моим добавленым контроллером, фабрикой и одной вьюхой.

Comment: Вот тут описано почему так происходит ( все дело в Options) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request/30296149#30296149. Как собственно и ответил ниже Константин

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться, исправлять

Comment: Незачто) На самом деле это не совсем ошибка, т.к. это своеобразный пинг на возможность доступа. В вашем случае (если есть доступ к серверу конечно), то легче всего просто разрешить options запросы. Ну а если нет такой возможности - то придется шаманить

Comment: доступ к серверу есть, так что думаю проблем не должно быть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что первым делом ангуляр отправляет запрос OPTIONS для проверка возможностей сервера. Поэтому вам надо этот  открыть метод на сервере, как пример на php header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE, OPTIONS'); 
в .htaccess это строчка
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

Comment: Большое спасибо! Исправил. Нашел сразу готовое решение для меня https://gist.github.com/nilcolor/816580

Comment: Пожалуйста, только не забудьте headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"; вместо звёздочки ваш ip указать. А то как то не безопасно будет